# How to divide datetime period into separate days in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to divide time period for example from:

```
2015-11-22 11:22:33 to 2015-11-24 02:02:04
```

into something like this:

```
2015-11-22 11:22:33 - 2015-11-22 23:59:59
2015-11-23 00:00:00 - 2015-11-23 23:59:59
2015-11-24 00:00:00 - 2015-11-24 02:02:04.
```

It has to work also for periods shorter than 24h, so for

```
2015-11-22 11:22:33 to 2015-11-23 02:02:04
```

I need this:

```
2015-11-22 11:22:33 - 2015-11-22 23:59:59
2015-11-23 00:00:00 - 2015-11-23 02:02:04.
```

I found almost perfect piece of code, but it only works for periods longer than 24h and I don't know how to tune it.

```
<?php
$start_date = '27:04:2013';
$start_time = '16:30';
$end_date = '29:04:2013';
$end_time = '22:30';

// Date input strings and generate a suitable DatePeriod
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat("d:m:Y H:i", "$start_date $start_time");
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat("d:m:Y H:i", "$end_date $end_time");
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    // Get midnight at start of current day
    $date_start = clone $date;
    $date_start->modify('midnight');

    // Get 23:59:59, end of current day
    // (moving to midnight of next day might be good too)
    $date_end = clone $date;
    $date_end->modify('23:59:59');

    // Take care of partial days
    $date_start = max($start, $date_start);
    $date_end = min($end, $date_end);

    // Here you would construct your array of
    // DateTime pairs, or DateIntervals, as you want.
    printf(
        "%s -> %s \n",
        $date_start->format('Y-m-d H:i'),
        $date_end->format('Y-m-d H:i')
    );
} 
?>
```

Comment: If I run your code with the following values(less than 24-hours):
Start: 27-04-2013 16:30
End: 27-04-2013 22:30

It returns:
2013-04-27 16:30 -> 2013-04-27 22:30 

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d02302fe7e21f3a599c74f4c49275255481feaad

What do you want to change about that?

Comment: Hello! I edited your question so it's easier to read.

Comment: Yes, it works but it doesn't for dates from my post. For example is period is 4h, but date changes from one day to other it only returns starting date to midnight ex. 2015-11-24 23:10:11 - 2015-11-24 23:59:59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date1 = '2015-11-22 11:22:33';
$date2 = '2015-11-23 12:22:34';

$f1 = strtotime($date1);
$f2 = strtotime(substr($date1, 0, 10) . " 23:59:59");

while($f2 < strtotime($date2)) {
    print(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$f1) .' - ' .date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$f2).'<br>');
    $f1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $f2) .' +1 second');
    $f2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $f2) .' +1 day');
}

print(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$f1) .' - ' .$date2.'<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77eaae15fdd7c0d2ca1f02a2d225c17199218819

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-11-22 11:22:33');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-11-23 02:02:04');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);


var_dump($interval->format('%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'));

// RESULT: string(14) "0-0-0 14:39:31"
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.format.php